# Terraform: How to iterate over multiple values in object

Tags: object, variables, terraform, set

Im trying to create a resource with a name and a description. Both are strings

**VARIABLES.TF**

variable "leaf_int_prof_group"{

```
type = object({
    name = string
    description = string
})
```

}

**TERRAFORM.TFVARS**

leaf_int_prof_group = {

```
{
   name = "Leaf_101"
   description = "This is a Leaf101"
}
{
   name = "Leaf_102"
   description = "This is a Leaf102"
}
{
   name = "Leaf_103"
   description = "This is a Leaf103"
}
```

}

**MAIN.TF**

How would i define the variables in main.tf (below doesnt seem to work??)

resource "aci_leaf_interface_profile" "LN_group" {

```
for_each = var.leaf_int_prof_group
    name = var.leaf_int_prof_group.name
    description = var.leaf_int_prof_group.description
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not a valid TF code. Perhaps  you want a list of objects:

```
variable "leaf_int_prof_group"{
    type = list(object({
        name = string
        description = string
    })) 
}
```

then

```
leaf_int_prof_group =  [
    {
       name = "Leaf_101"
       description = "This is a Leaf101"
    },
    {
       name = "Leaf_102"
       description = "This is a Leaf102"
    },
    {
       name = "Leaf_103"
       description = "This is a Leaf103"
    }   
]
```

and finally:

```
resource "some_resource" "some_name" {
    for_each    = {for idx, val in var.leaf_int_prof_group: idx => val}
    name        = each.value.name
    description = each.value.description
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this problem. First week of programming. Ive added the code as above. Getting the following error │ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on leaf_int_profile.tf line 17, in resource "aci_leaf_interface_profile" "LN_group":
│   17:     description = var.leaf_int_prof_group.description
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.leaf_int_prof_group is a list of object, known only after apply
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "description" for a specific element of the  
│ list, or across all elements of the list?

Comment: Just a small amendment : in the for loop i removed ".name" from the variable and all worked. Thank you for your Help :)